# How to add custom HTML in woo-commerec shop page?

Tags: wordpress

How can I add custom HTML in woo-commerce shop page?

I see in `archive-product.php` file having html that I want to replace with my custom HTML. In this file

`do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );`

bring the HTML source code that I want replace.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content" role="main">
```

The above HTML code on shop page is dynamic. So on which file I need to replace this code.

Comment: You can override archive-product.php file in child theme

Comment: Is there not any simple way that I can simply replace HTML ? I know its possible .

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the action only for the archive-product page and add your own like this.

```
if (is_shop()){
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'action_woocommerce_before_main_content', 10, 2 ); //removes default action
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'YOUR_CUSTOM_ACTION_woocommerce_before_main_content', 10 );
}

function YOUR_CUSTOM_ACTION_woocommerce_before_main_content(){
  echo "This will be placed before your content";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

open file wrapper-start.php under woocommerce/template/wrapper-start.php
and make changes what ever you want

```
switch( $template ) {
case 'twentyeleven' :
    echo '<div id="primary"><div id="content" role="main" class="twentyeleven">';
    break;
case 'twentytwelve' :
    echo '<div id="primary" class="site-content"><div id="content" role="main" class="twentytwelve">';
    break;
case 'twentythirteen' :
    echo '<div id="primary" class="site-content"><div id="content" role="main" class="entry-content twentythirteen">';
    break;
case 'twentyfourteen' :
    echo '<div id="primary" class="content-area"><div id="content" role="main" class="site-content twentyfourteen"><div class="tfwc">';
    break;
case 'twentyfifteen' :
    echo '<div id="primary" role="main" class="content-area twentyfifteen"><div id="main" class="site-main t15wc">';
    break;
default :
    echo '<div class="row"><div class="container">';
    break;
}
```